# How to wait for an element to be present in a bUnit test?

Tags: blazor, bunit

Let's say I have a test like the one below. **Is there a way to wait for an element to be present in the markup of a rendered component?**

```cs
[Fact]
public void Component_DoesSomething()
{
    // Arrange
    var ctx = new TestContext();
    var unitUnderTest = ctx.RenderComponent<SomeComponent>();

    var selector = "tbody";
            
    // Act
    var tableBody = unitUnderTest.Find(selector);

    // Assert
    Assert.Contains(tableBody.InnerHtml, "someStuff");
}
```

I've reviewed the docs below, but I don't see anything indicating how to wait for an element.

- [Awaiting Async State](https://bunit.dev/docs/interaction/awaiting-async-state.html)
- [Async Assertion](https://bunit.dev/docs/verification/async-assertion.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IRenderedComponent.WaitForElement()` method. See the code below:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Component_DoesSomething()
{
    // Arrange
    var ctx = new TestContext();
    var unitUnderTest = ctx.RenderComponent<SomeComponent>();

    var selector = "tbody";
    unitUnderTest.WaitForElement(selector);

    // Act
    var tableBody = unitUnderTest.Find(selector);

    // Assert
    Assert.Contains(tableBody.InnerHtml, "someStuff");
}
```

See also: `WaitForElements()`

Comment: You can actually write `var tableBody = unitUnderTest.WaitForElement(selector);` and skip the `var tableBody = unitUnderTest.Find(selector);` line. Setting a timeout should normally not be needed. It defaults to one second, and you should only need to set it when know that the async operation takes longer than 1 second.